# My Silverstone es02-usb is not working as expected

Tags: usb, remote

I recently bought a Silver Stone ES02-USB and it works mostly as advertised except for the most important part. This product is a remote start for a PC. I intend to have my PC set up in the closet of my recording studio to have the quietest environment to record acoustic instruments.

The Silver Stone ES02-USB works in every way except powering the computer from an off position. So it shuts down and resets my PC when it is powered on, but it won't power my PC on from a 'cold start' with the power switch on. I think I need to modify settings in my BIOS/UEFI but I can't find them on my MSI MPG X570 Gaming Pro Carbon WiFi motherboard. I have already searched for help and found none. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To be clearer because my question was closed with no feedback, what would settings on an MSI mobo to allow power to a USB hub while the computer is off. Or if you have a better suggestion as to why it isn't working I would be thrilled for feedback.

Comment: Try to disable _ErP Ready_ and enable _Resume by USB device_.

Comment: For the 3rd time. I already told you what to do "check in motherboard's BIOS / UEFI menu to make sure USB power on is enabled"

Comment: This was my first expierience using Super User. It was awful. I tried to post a simple question in which I forgot name my mobo. Then a user flags and deletes it with no feedback. So I repost it. I had already posted on Stack Exchange mistaking the place to post this question. Then I was immediately attacked by 4 power user who did not read any of my posts or the changes to them before repeatedly telling me wrong answer, while also making me feel stupid for doing so.

Comment: Eventually I saw the one helpful comment that I needed to name my mobo so I reposted. Then I have David Postill telling me the wrong thing several times & again making me feel stupid. He told me to use comment. I could not because I did not have 50 rep. Eventually Gronostaj saved the day by approaching the post with a minimum of effort and a basic attempt at friendliness and not in an effort to shame the new guy. I don't want to be involved with the Super User community like I am with the Music Stack and regular bc of the way I was treated on this first experience. Just so you all know.